# Can't ping switch from WLC Cisco 3750G

Tags: networking, cisco

Working with a Catalyst 3750G with the integrated WLAN controller. Management VLAN ID is 55 on both the switch and the controller, both on the same VLAN and subnet with the same default gateway. However, I am unable to reach or connect to the controller from the switch and vice versa. If I directly connect to the switch I can ping default gateway, reach internet, etc. However, when I try to ping the management IP address for the controller I am unable to.

I was able to reach the device manager GUI after resetting the config on the controller but unable to reach or connect to it aside from serial console.

edit:
Switch config: https://pastebin.com/u3bYC5Kw

Will get WLC config later today, sorry

Comment: Please edit your question to include the device configuration.  Otherwise, we're just guessing.

Answer (score -1):

You can't have access and trunk configuration on interface Gi 1/0/27. It's a bad configuration.

Rergards,

KV

Comment: Access port commands are ignored when the port is in Trunk mode.